# How to perform Insert statement by decoding Base64 in express

Tags: node.js, express, base64, node-mysql

How to decode the param values received which were received as Base64 encoded form and insert into database ?

This is what i have tried.

- According to this i am getting one value recieved from the client as
  param value and inserting into server ( I have recieved the request
  at POST )
- No `base64` encoding is done here

I am using this code at present :

```
var express = require('express')
 , async = require('async')
 , http = require('http')
 , mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: '******',
   password: "******",
   database: 'posting_information_DB'
});

connection.connect();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1234);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


app.post('/Name/',function(request,response,next){


app.use(express.bodyParser());

   var keyName=request.query.Key;
   var name_of_restaurants;
   async.series( [

       function(callback) {

          connection.query('INSERT INTO details (name) VALUES (?)', [keyName], function (err, rows, fields) 
              {
                      console.log('Connection result error ' + err);        
                      callback();
              });
       }

  // Send the response
] );
} );


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

What i am trying to do !

- Now what changes should i need to make so that when i need recieve a
  `image` and `string` as two param values
- These values are Base64 encoded
- How to decode these Base64 here and then insert the retrieved param
  values to database

How to modify my posted Express code !

Thanks !

Comment: You can decode base64 with a buffer object: `new Buffer(b64string, 'base64').toString('binary')`

Comment: @ Michael Tang ..... Can you Edit the code with your solution as your answer ? ..... I am a newbie !

Comment: also, I think you're misusing caolan's async library. you might want to define a callback for the async.series call itself, so you can take an action after your query is done. check out the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#series). however, since you only have one async function in series and you are already utilizing it's callback, you might not even need the async library (just stick your `res.send()` or such in the query callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `image` parameter using [`request.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) and then create a [Buffer object, specify the `base64` encoding](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) and then convert it using the [`.toString()`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method.

```
app.post('/Name/', function(request, response, next){
  var image = new Buffer(request.params.image, 'base64').toString('binary');
  // do the database insert...
});
```